# Get coverage report without phpunit

Tags: php, code-coverage, xdebug

I'm having a problem to get coverage report from phpunit/php-code-coverage.

When I do:

```php
xdebug_start_code_coverage();
// code
print_r(xdebug_get_code_coverage());
```

I get the coverage information as expected. I decided to use the phpunit/php-code-coverage to handle the export of the result. I'm trying to use like suggested on the repository:

```php
$coverage = new \SebastianBergmann\CodeCoverage\CodeCoverage;
$coverage->start();
// code
$coverage->stop();
$writer = new \SebastianBergmann\CodeCoverage\Report\Clover;
$writer->process($coverage, '/tmp/clover.xml');
```

Then the result is empty. When I use the `xdebug_get_code_coverage()` to see if theres some result, is also empty. If i remove the `$coverage->stop()` I get results, but just with the `xdebug_get_code_coverage()` function, not with the package.
I don't know if I have to do something different to get this working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An additional step is required. Add the files you want coverage to the whitelist.

```php
$driver = \SebastianBergmann\CodeCoverage\Driver\Xdebug;
$filter = new \SebastianBergmann\CodeCoverage\Filter;
$filter->addDirectoryToWhitelist('/directory');
$coverage = new \SebastianBergmann\CodeCoverage\CodeCoverage($driver, $filter);
$coverage->start();
// code
$coverage->stop();
$writer = new \SebastianBergmann\CodeCoverage\Report\Clover;
$writer->process($coverage, '/tmp/clover.xml');
```